# How to create long Solution Explorer screenshot in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

How to create long Solution Explorer screenshot in Visual Studio?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zIub.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) has a [scrolling capture mode](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-snagit-using-all-in-one-capture.html) and [some other tricks](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-snagit-scrolling-troubleshoot.html#3) that can produce that kind of screenshot.